# Why my code for the rock-paper-scissors-pencil-fire with dictionary doesn't work?

Tags: python-3.x

My code doesn't compare two values to produce the right outcome in a rock-paper-scissors game. it seems like there is something wrong with the dictionary or the way i compare the choices of the player and the computer. For example sometimes the player chooses paper and the computer chooses rock and it gives a tie.

This is my code in python 3

```
#Game:
#The player must choose his weapon and 'fight' against the computer 
#following the rules above.
#The player can choose between the following: Rock, Scissors, Fire, 
#Pencil and Paper.
#Rules: The rock beats the scissors, the scissors beat the fire, the fire 
#beats the pencil, the pencil beats the paper and the paper beats the 
#rock

#Player1 is the human player
#Player2 is the computer
import random
#The game keeps how many times the player1 has won, lost or tied with the 
computer in the variables bellow.
wins = 0
losses = 0
ties = 0
#The game welcomes the player.
print("Welcome to the Rock-Paper-Scissors-Fire-Pencil game!")
#The hierarchy of which weapon beats another is added in a dictionary and 
#the choices of the player in a table.
rules = {'rock': {'scissors', 'pencil', 'fire'}, 'scissors': {'paper', 
'pencil'}, 'fire': {'pencil', 'paper', 'scissors'}, 'pencil': 'paper', 
'paper': 'rock'}
choices = ['rock', 'scissors', 'fire', 'pencil', 'paper']
#The player can play as many times as he/she wants until he/she type 
#anything else except yes in the "Do you want to play again?" question.
play_again = "yes"

while play_again == "yes":

    player1 = None
    while player1 not in choices: 
#The player must choose his/her 'weapon'
        player1 = input("\n PLAYER 1 - Please make a choice 
 (rock/paper/scissors/fire/pencil):")
#The computer chooses it's 'weapon'.       
    random_number = random.randint(0,4)
    player2 = choises[random_number]

#The game shows the choices of the players.    
    print (f"\nPlayer 1 has chosen {player1}")
    print (f"\nPlayer 2 has chosen {player2}")

#The game compares the choices of the players and announces if the human 
#player won, lost or tied with the computer.
#Then it adds the win, the lost or the tie to the summary of wins, losses 
#or ties.
    if rules[player2] == player1:
        print('Player1 wins the round!')
        wins += 1
    elif rules[player1] == player2:
        print('Player2 wins the round!')
        losses += 1
    else:
        print('The round is a tie!')
        ties += 1
#The game asks the player if he/she wants to play again.      
    play_again = input("\nDo you want to play again?:")
#If the player doesn't want to play again, the game prints the results of 
#all the rounds of the game and closes.
else:
    print(f"The player1 won {wins} times")
    print(f"The player1 lost {losses} times")
    print(f"The player1 tied {ties} times")
    print("\n Good Bye")
```

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:
1) Indent your comments with the code.
2) `rules[player1]` returns a `set`, why would the `set` match an individual `str`?
3) `random` can choose a random element for you.
See my code below. I tried to put a `##########` before all my changes.

```
import random

wins, losses, ties = 0, 0, 0

print("Wellcome to the Rock-Paper-Scissors-Fire-Pencil game!")

rules = {'rock': {'scissors', 'pencil', 'fire'}, 'scissors': {'paper', 
'pencil'}, 'fire': {'pencil', 'paper', 'scissors'}, 'pencil': 'paper', 
'paper': 'rock'}
############ This should be a set not a list (faster look up time)
choices = {'rock', 'scissors', 'fire', 'pencil', 'paper'}

play_again = "yes"

while play_again == "yes":

    player1_choice = None
    while player1_choice not in choices: 
        player1_choice = input("\n PLAYER 1 - Please make a choice (rock/paper/scissors/fire/pencil):")

    ######### Random can choose for you.
    player2_choice = random.choice(list(choices))

    print (f"\nPlayer 1 has choosen {player1_choice}")
    print (f"\nPlayer 2 has choosen {player2_choice}")

    ########## Don't use ==, use `in` for sets.
    if player1_choice in rules[player2_choice]:
        print('Player 2 wins the round!')
        wins += 1
    elif player2_choice in rules[player1_choice]:
        print('Player 1 wins the round!')
        losses += 1
    else:
        print('The round is a tie!')
        ties += 1

    play_again = input("\nDo you want to play again?:")

########## Why was there an `else` here?
print(f"The player1 won {wins} times")
print(f"The player1 lost {losses} times")
print(f"The player1 tied {ties} times")
print("\n Good Bye")
```